# Forcing the mobile view while using an iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm not sure if this is actually possible but here is my dilemma.  I want to embed a website which has a responsive layout, meaning, on desktop view it will show content in two columns, but on mobile view it will show them in one column.

The website seem to detect the width of the browser and adjust the columns accordingly.

I want it so when my website is in its mobile view, and has that other website embedded within it, it can force the embedded website to show the mobile view.  Is there a way to force/trick the embedded website adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force iframe to show embed website in mobile view.
you can do it by setting it's width according to the device width

```
for example:-
<iframe src="https://amazon.com" width="320"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://amazon.com" width="567"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://amazon.com" width="768"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://amazon.com" width="991"></iframe>
```